# Hay algun modo de hacer una llamada (abrir la aplicación del usuario) con HTML?

Tags: html, enlace

Quiero hacer que, al hacer click a un enlace, se le abra la aplicación "llamadas" al usuario, y que me llame a mi telefono (655456789 (no es mi verdadero telefono)). Hay algun modo de hacer esto?

Código:
`<a href="abrir_la_app">Llamarme</a>`

Yo puse el `href` por poner algo, esto no significa que si no se puede hacer con el `href` no se pueda hacer de otro modo.

Alguien sabe como hacerlo?(Si es possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás te sirva un enlace en modo `tel`.

```html
<a href="tel:655456789">655 456 789</a>
```